# Traveling salesperson - budget to cities

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

An ice cream factory holds n branches S1,S2,... Sn in the world. A salesperson has to go through each one of the branches to pick up different products.

1. When the salesperson finishes his job in branch 1<= j <= n, he gets Mj money to his budget (which is initially 0)
2. For j <= n - 1 from branch Sj a plane leaves to the next branch, Sj+1, that costs Cj money.

From the last branch, Sn, a plane leaves to the first branch, S1, that costs Cn money.

We know that the accumulated amount of money, Mj (sigma from j = 1 to n) equals the amount of money he spends Cj (sigma from j = 1 to n). The salesperson has to pay for the planes with the money he recieves from the branches. The company lets the salesperson decide wherever he will start his journey, for free (and he'll finish his trip there).

How can I prove that there's always 1 <= j <= n so that if the salesperson will start his journey from Sj, he could finish his journey with his budget?

I thought about the Pigeonhole principle, but can't really formalize my thoughts. any other suggestions will be great as well!

Comment: So the sum of all the money he receives is equal to the sum of what he pays for flights? Are you trying to ensure that the money he currently has never goes negative?

Comment: I'm trying to ensure even a harder case, which the money never goes negative, and there's always a "node" that he can start from, which he'll finish the trip traveling everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Think about how much money he will have at each city if we allow the amount to go negative and he keeps going round multiple times.

The money will follow some periodic pattern with period n.

If we start at the city where he has the least amount of money, then the pattern will always stay non-negative so he will have enough to complete the route.

### Additional explanation

Define S(k) to be the sum with i ranging from 0 to k of Mi-Ci.
S(k) represents the amount of money that the salesman will have after travelling from city 0 to k and buying the next plane ticket out.

We know that S(n) is equal to 0.

Let m be the value for x that minimizes S(x).

Then travelling from city m to city i will cost S(i)-S(m), which will always be greater than or equal to zero by construction.

Comment: This is really interesting, but I can't seem to find a way to formalize it

I tried to solve this question with an induction approach, to define an induction phrase, like "The traveling salesperson will always have appropriate amount of money to travel whole cities", to prove the trivial base of the induction, and assuming for K cities, for K + 1, only one more city, to (somehow) proof that this one more city doesn't really matter, and the whole proof is pretty much done

Comment: I've added some more details that may help with a formalization

Comment: Thank you very much! So, basically I could say that Sm will **always** be a proper way to start in? can I also say that if the route will go negative again, It will contradict the minimality of the Sm branch?

Comment: I think I got it, if any anomalies are found, please let me know (I think the ending isn't so good).
To find such a j, let assume that we can travel every city, even with a negative amount of current money (after the traversal).
After a whole iteration, we'll check the salesperson current money count.
Define S(k) as the sum from 0 to k for Mi - Ci. S(k) represents the amount of money after each travel. we know that S(n) = 0.
When the iteration is over, we'll find m = Min(S(k)). if m = 0, we found j. if m < 0, S(i) - S(m) > = 0. If not, we contradict m being. So, m could be chosen as first

Comment: Just be careful when writing Min(S(k)) to distinguish between the smallest value that S(k) takes, and the index where S(k) takes its smallest value.  In your comment you seem to sometimes use m to represent the index, and elsewhere to represent the value.  In my answer, m always represents the index, and S(m) is the value.

Comment: Thank you so much.